# How to reload a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery.

I have to reload a div after sending some values to server using ajax.

My jQuery code is

```
selectionChanged: function () {
var $selectedRows = $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable('selectedRows');
$selectedRows.each(function () {

    var record = $(this).data('record');
    var columnname = record.columnname;
    var datatype = record.datatype;
    var columnlength = record.columnlength;
    $.post('meta?action=dataload', {
        columnname: columnname, datatype: datatype, columnlength: columnlength
    });

});
```

after this code is executed I want to reload a div

```
<div id="loadedtablecontainer"></div>
```

this div will get the selected data of 1st jtable ..  and display it in this jtable.

So by using this div id I have to call or reload this div soon after above jQuery function got executed

Something like

```
$.post('meta?action=dataload', {
    columnname: columnname, datatype: datatype, columnlength: columnlength
});

$("#loadedtablecontainer");
```

Answer (score 1):

So I am assuming the Ajax call returns the new content, so set the html() in the callback.

```
$.post('meta?action=dataload', 
   {
      columnname : columnname,
      datatype:datatype,
      columnlength:columnlength
   },
   function (data) {
       $( "#loadedtablecontainer" ).html(data);
   }
);
```

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do with it. Loop through it and build a string in the format you want and set the html.

Answer (score 1):

You have a callback parameter which returns your result from post. Use that to manipulate the data and form the HTML. Then simply append it

```
   $.post('meta?action=dataload', {
          columnname : columnname, datatype:datatype,columnlength:columnlength
       },
       function (result) {
           // make your manipulations here, (Ex: var manipulatedHTML )
           $("#loadedtablecontainer" ).append(manipulatedHTML );
       }
    );
```

If its a json

```
function(result) { 
 //result is your json 
 var manipulatedHTML = '<div class="result">'+result.value"+'</div>'; 
} 
$("#loadedtablecontainer" ).append(manipulatedHTML )
```

Use a for loop if its a json array

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadCustomerCorpPopup(id) {
        $("#eBody").mask("${loading}");
        $.ajax({
            url : '${url}/customer/ajax_customer_corporate_popup',
            data : {
                customerCorporateId : id,
            },
            dataType : 'text',
            cache : false,
            success : function(data) {
                $('#popupId').html(data);
                $('#popupId').modal('show');
                $("#eBody").unmask("${loading}");
            }
        });
    }
```

You can use this way `$('#popupId').html(data);`
**data** can a html code or url.